# Maximum date difference between rows for distinct users

Tags: mysql, date, datediff

Take a simple table such as:

```
User ID | Connection Date
1   | 12/10/2011
2   | 12/12/2011
1   | 12/14/2011
3   | 12/15/2011
1   | 12/16/2011
2   | 12/17/2011
2   | 12/18/2011
1   | 12/19/2011
3   | 12/20/2011
4   | 12/21/2011
2   | 12/21/2011
```

I would like to calculate the maximum date difference between a users connections.

Thanks

Comment: "maximum date difference" please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

In days ...

```
select user_id, max(conn_date) - min(conn_date) from conn
group by user_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

try as below

```
select 
  mainqry.userid,
  max(mainqry.daysdiff) as max_date_diff
From
(
select 
  qry.userid,
  -- qry.id1,
  -- qry.currid,
  ( Case when qry.id1 = qry.currid then qry.dt1 else null end ) prevconndt,
  qry.currdt,
  datediff((Case when qry.id1 = qry.currid then qry.dt1 else null end),qry.currdt) daysdiff
from 
(
select 
  userid,
  @previd id1,
  @previd := userid as currid,
  @prevdt dt1,
  @prevdt := connectiondate as currdt
from table1,(select @prevdt:=NULL,@previd := NULL) a  
order by userid, connectiondate desc
) qry 
) MainQry
group by MainQry.userid;
```

It will output below for your given data

```
Userid max_date_diff
1      4
2      5 
3      5 
4      Null
```

you can also verify it using below ...

```
select 
qry.userid,
-- qry.id1,
-- qry.currid,
( Case when qry.id1 = qry.currid then qry.dt1 else null end ) prevconndt,
qry.currdt,
datediff((Case when qry.id1 = qry.currid then qry.dt1 else null end),qry.currdt) daysdiff
from 
(
select 
  userid,
  @previd id1,
  @previd := userid as currid,
  @prevdt dt1,
  @prevdt := connectiondate as currdt
from table1,(select @prevdt:=NULL,@previd := NULL) a  
order by userid, connectiondate desc
) qry
```